# If the restriction of a differential form to a closed submanifold is closed, is the form itself closed?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be a smooth manifold and let $i:Y\hookrightarrow X$ be a closed embedding of a closed submanifold $Y$ in $X$. It is well-known that the sheaves of smooth differential operators $\Omega_X^{p}$ are fine, which means that they are soft, in particular. That is, the map

$$i^{*}:\Omega^{p}_X(X)\to i_*i^{*}\Omega_X^p(X)=\Omega_{X|Y}^p(Y)$$

is surjective. Assume now that $\alpha$ is a closed $p$-form on $Y$. Then, by the softness property, there is a $p$-form $\beta$ on $X$ such that $i^*\beta=\alpha$. Since $\alpha$ is a cocycle, we have

$$[\alpha]=[i^*\beta].$$

Is it true that

$$[\alpha]=i^*[\beta]?$$

We know that the pullback commutes with the differential but $\beta$ is just a p-form, it is not closed, so the class $[\beta]$ of an arbitrary form $\beta$ does not make sense, unless $\beta$ is a closed form, which is not guaranteed.

Comment: One can make sense of $[\beta]$ even though it is usually not done. But what is your question?

Comment: Thank you Moishe Kohan. My first question is: how do you make sense of $[\beta]$ if $\beta$ is not closed? My second question is: If $\alpha$ is a closed form on $Y$ and $i^*\beta=\alpha$, then it makes sense to write $[i^*\beta]=[\alpha]$. But does $[i^*\beta]=i^*[\beta]$ make sense as $\beta$ does not descend to a class if it is not closed. That is my problem.

Comment: Just an element of the vector space $\Omega^p(X)/d \Omega^{p-1}(X)$.

Comment: For your 2nd question: of course, it does, just you have to forget the cohomology.

Comment: So, given an arbitrary $p$-form $\beta$, the notation $[\beta]$ means an equivalence class in the quotient $\Omega_X^p(X)/d\Omega_X^{p-1}(X)$, is that right?

Comment: Of course.......

Comment: For the $2$nd question: What do you mean that I have to forget the cohomology. In the sense that $[\beta]$ is not a closed form?

Comment: Of course.......

Comment: If $[\beta]$ is a class in $\Omega_X^p(X)/d\Omega_X^{p-1}(X)$ and $[\gamma]$ and $[\delta]$ are de Rham cohomology classes such that $[\beta]\cup[\gamma]=[\delta]$, can we infer that $[\beta]$ is a cohomology class or that is not enough?

Comment: No, but you shouldn't ask new questions in comments.

Comment: Good - that is what I thought, as well. I am not asking a "new" question. It is a follow-up question which clarifies the nature of $[\beta]$....